# How to change Application Culture at runtime for DataGrid(Localization)?

Tags: wpf, culture, currentculture

I have changed the Application culture at run-time by using different resource file. But it is not reflect in data grid which displays the old one.
Changing culture :

```
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");
```

How can get notification while changing culture at run-time?

Anyone suggest other way to achieve this?

Regards,
Srinivasan

Answer (score 1):

You have to change it like you have done

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar");
```

But unfortunately you have to reload all (localized) controls to get it work.

Look at this : [WPF: How to change the CurrentUICulture at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626627/wpf-how-to-change-the-currentuiculture-at-runtime)