# Change CurrentUICulture at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that supports multiple languages.

I saw this answer to the question [Best way to implement multi-language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35813707/12417300) (using .resx files) here on Stackoverflow.
Everything works great except that the language doesn't change at runtime.

I have seen this answer to the question [How to change the CurrentUICulture at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627042/12417300) here on Stackoverflow but unfortunately his answer does not help me because the link he posted in his solution does not work.

I saw a lot of articles on google but no success.

A little attempt of mine (**.cs**):

```
private void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string item = ((ComboBoxItem)sender).Content.ToString();

    switch (item)
    {
        case "English":
            Console.WriteLine("English");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
            Product.Language.Resources.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
            break;

        case "German":
            Product.Language.Resources.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
            Console.WriteLine("German");
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("none");
            break;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label x:Name="LabelHeader1" Content="{x:Static language1:Resources.LanguageTL}" />
            <Label x:Name="LabelHeader2" Content="{x:Static language1:Resources.HomeTL}" />
            <Label x:Name="LabelHeader3" Content="{x:Static language1:Resources.SkyTL}" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="Languages">
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">English</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>German</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <EventSetter Event="ComboBox.PreviewMouseDown" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler" />
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

The keys are saved in `.resx` files:

[image: .resx file screenshot]

And thanks for the help

Comment: I would suggest you to look into official guide on MSDN for localization of a WPF app, using the LocBaml tool from Wpf samples. Look for localization and globalization for WPF. Best way to localize a WPF app is to follow offiical guidelines.
https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Tools/LocBaml

Comment: @ToreAurstad But the method used by Rans with resx files is equally valid and in fact for some scenario much simpler.

Comment: I suppose that you have to force WPF to re-load the values set via "{x:Static ...}". Basically you would have to re-load the whole UI, It will be easier if you repace the "{x:Static ..}" by something allowng for dynamic values like a "{Binding ...}" to a property in the view model or the [LocalizationExtension](https://github.com/XAMLMarkupExtensions/WPFLocalizationExtension).